# Hiding Route Property in Swagger

Tags: c#, .net, swagger

Is there a way I can hide a custom property of the route in Swagger JSON definition? I have another application that invokes the API and it reads Swagger to get more information.

For example, I want to indicate that route requires Active Directory. The calling application will execute a validation to make sure AD is available.

I looked at OperationsFilter but that inserts a Parameter into the Swagger definition. I also considered using Tag but it doesn't accomplish what I need, and it messes with UI.

We use Swagger Annotations in .NET Core 2.0 project. Ideally, I want to do this through annotations but haven't found anything I can use.

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/")]
    [SwaggerOperation(
        Summary = "Some Service",
        Description = "Some Service",
        OperationId = "getMyStuff",
        Tags = new[] { "MyStuff" }
    )]
    [SwaggerResponse(200, "Response object returned")]
    [SwaggerResponse(400, "Response object returned")]
    public ActionResult<Response> GetStuff()
    {...code here...}
```

Comment: Is this Swashbuckle or Swagger-Net?

Comment: This is Swashbuckle

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer. Basically, I am adding an extension that is route specific.

Define custom attribute class

```
// allow mutliple attributes specified in data annotations
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = true)]
// model for custom attribute class
public class CustomAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string ParameterName { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public CustomAttribute(string parameterName, string value, string description = null)
    {
        this.ParameterName = parameterName;
        this.Value = value;
        this.Description = description;
    }
}
```

Create swagger operations filter

```
public class CustomAttributeOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    // variables
    MethodInfo _methodInfo;

    public void Apply(Operation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        context.ApiDescription.TryGetMethodInfo(out _methodInfo);

        var attributes = _methodInfo.GetCustomAttributes<CustomAttribute>();
        foreach (var atrib in attributes)
            operation.Extensions.Add(atrib.ParameterName, atrib.Value);
    }
}
```

In startups.cs update swagger registration to include custom operations filter

```
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("helloworld", new Info {Title = "HelloWorld API"});
            c.EnableAnnotations();
            c.OperationFilter<CustomAttributeOperationFilter>();

        });
```

Finally, specify custom attributes on the API definition

```
    [HttpGet]
    [CustomAttribute("x-accept-apples, "yes")]
    [CustomAttribute("x-accept-pears, "no")]
    public ActionResult<Response> Get()
    {
        return Ok();
    }
```